# Consult data on table , fields are related to each other

Tags: sql-server

Hello guys Im just starting with SQl server,

Sorce data

```
type    num1    num2    date1         
   A      1       2   01/01/2019    
   b      1           01/02/2019
   b      3           05/02/2017
   a      1       1   03/02/2019    
   a      2       3   15/03/2018    
   b      2           20/12/2018
```

Expected result

```
type    num1    num2    date1         'date2' 
   a      1       2   01/01/2019    20/12/2018
   a      1       1   03/02/2019    01/02/2019
   a      2       3   15/03/2018    05/02/2017
```

this is the best i made until now, and my date2 are all messed up im not getting the correct values , and i still have the problem with dates that the same number can exist in diferent years num1 1 type b exist in 2017 and 2019

```
select c1.type, c1.num1, c1.num2, c1.date, c2.date as 'date2'
from t1 c1
inner join t1 c2 on c2.num2=c1.num1
order by c1.type
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What are you expecting? What are you trying to get? Show an example of your desired results.

Comment: the expected result is'Date2'

Comment: Pleas read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve first. We don't know neither the definition nor the content of your second table. I guess nobody will be able to help with the information you provided

Comment: You want it to output only the "Date2" column? In that case don't include all the other columns in the SELECT statement. But are you really saying it should only return certain rows as well? P.S. "all messed up" and "not getting the correct values" and "still have the problem"...none of these are issues we can fix. They are vague, almost meaningless statements with no proper details. You have given us a sample of the table containing the source data. Now please show us a table of the final result you expect, and also explain what the rules are which mean that those are the results you want.

Comment: sorry guys, my bad, guess this represent better what i need

Comment: That's one part. Now the other part of what I asked you: _Why_ are those the expected results? What business rule is the query supposed to implement? (I ask this, because we could write a query which appears to return exactly those rows, but it might not use the right criteria to do that, so it then might not work properly on other data in your table)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is as simple as:

```
SELECT
    t1.[type],
    t1.num1,
    t1.num2,
    t1.date1,
    t2.date1 AS date2
FROM
    t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.num1 = t1.num2 AND t2.num2 IS NULL
ORDER BY
    t1.[type];
```

But note that I had to make the requirement up to some degree, as it wasn't entirely clear from your question.

Comment: And with your amendment this should obviously be an `INNER` rather than `LEFT OUTER` join

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is join on yourself, then allow date

```
Declare @table1 table (type Char(1)
                    ,num1 int
                    ,num2 int
                    ,date1 date)
    insert into @table1 (type,num1,num2,date1)
    values

    ('a',1,2,'2019-01-01')
    ,('b',1,null,'2019-01-02')
    ,('b',3,null,'2017-05-02')
    ,('a',1,1,'2019-03-02')
    ,('a',2,3,'2018-03-15')
    ,('b',2,null,'2018-12-20')


    select t.*,t2.date1 'Date2'
    from @table1 t
    inner join @table1 t2
    on t.num2 = t2.num1
    and t.type = 'a'
    and t2.type = 'b'
```